# Is there a better more flexible framing material for screens than aluminum kits?

Tags: windows, screens

Our windows are old and do not lend themselves to easy removal of the screens. In fact when I remove a screen I frequently bend it beyond repair. Is there a better more flexible framing material for screens than the aluminum kits from home depot?  You'd think better technology would exist.

Comment: How are you removing them? Typically there is space in the track so you can pull up and out to remove it without destroying the frame.

Comment: Not in these old ones.  It is ridiculously awkward.

Comment: Can you take a picture? That'd help us figure out what you have. On old windows, screens are usually part of the retrofitted storm windows, which are separate from the actual window structure itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look for wood or plastic window frames. They have a mechanism for screen replacement. [image: crossection of frame] Both are very flexible and robust materials.
You can remove one side of the frame and replace the screen then.

Comprehensive explanation to the picture can be found [online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulated_glazing)

Comment: I'm not sure what cross sections of insulated glazing have to do with screens.

Comment: The question was about better material than aluminum.

Comment: Ah, I think the OP was referring to seasonal removal, though. Not sure those windows are designed to have the panes removed frequently.